# NativeScript: how to make view 'transparent' for any user interactions

Tags: nativescript

Is there a way to make a view 'transparent' to any user interactions? For example I have a view (with transparent background) and a button under that view. I want the user could tap the button under that view. If I have a scroller view under that view I want the user interacts with scroller when scroll over that view, so the view doesn't interfere or intercept user's gestures. But only this view should be transparent to user's interactions not its children. So, if I have a button inside that view it behaves normally.

Example XML:

```
<AbsoluteLayout width="100%" height="100%">
    <Button text="Button1" tap="onTap1" />
    <GridLayout width="100%" height="100%" backgroundColor="transparent">
        <Button text="Button2" tap="onTap2" horizontalAlignment="center" verticalAlignment="center"/>
    </GridLayout>
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple approaches to make a view change its color in NativeScript.
For example you can directly change its backgroundColor. Another oiption is to use animation and third option is to use CSS-animation.
Here is a basic example for the first two options.

page.xml

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" navigatingTo="navigatingTo">
  <StackLayout>
      <GridLayout width="300" height="300" id="myGrid" backgroundColor="transparent">
      </GridLayout>
      <Button text="Tap me" tap="onTap" />
      <Button text="Or Tap me" tap="onAnotherTap" />
  </StackLayout>
</Page>
```

page.js

```
import { EventData } from "data/observable";
import { Page } from "ui/page";
import { HelloWorldModel } from "./main-view-model";
import { GridLayout } from "ui/layouts/grid-layout";

import { Color } from "color";

var myGridView;


export function navigatingTo(args: EventData) {

    var page = <Page>args.object;
    page.bindingContext = new HelloWorldModel();

    // get refference to the view using its id
    myGridView = <GridLayout>page.getViewById("myGrid");  
}

export function onTap(args:EventData) {
    var color = new Color("#FF0000");

    myGridView.backgroundColor = color;
}

export function onAnotherTap(args:EventData) {
    myGridView.animate({
        backgroundColor: new Color("#3D5AFE"),
        duration: 3000
    });
}
```

All of the options can be found described in [NativeScript documenation](https://docs.nativescript.org/)

Comment: Hi Nick, I know how to make the background transparent. I would like that view to be 'transparent' for user's interactions. In a way that when say there is a scroller under that view. User could interact with the scroller, but the view wouldn't intercept gestures. I also a bit extended my question.

Comment: backgrondColor only changes the visual represenation of the Color of your view... tarnsparent does not make it "disappear" in any way only makes the view transparent.. what you need to set instead is the visibility - you can set it to collapsed which wil entirely remove the view as it was not renedered at all. for example     myGridView.visibility = "collapsed";

Comment: https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/modules/_ui_enums_.visibility.html  however with this property your view wont take any space at all

Comment: Nope, that's not what I need. As I stated in my question I can have some child elements inside that view that should be visible and intractable. What would help is something like bubbling of the gestures deeper.